# Get Swift Playgrounds back? iOS 10 GM Warning

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift-playground, ios10

I just updated to the final release of iOS 10.0.1 on iPad Pro 12.9 inch

Swift Playgrounds is gone, and it's not in the App Store.

I've lost all my Playgrounds, I presume. No great loss.

But how do I get Swift Playgrounds back?

and... how do I warn other Swift Playground users about this?

### EDIT: UPDATE

Playgrounds is now in the App Store!!!

Comment: This is not a programming question. Perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com would be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Playgrounds will be released later this year.

> Free in the App Store this fall

http://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/